# Scala infix operator working weird

Tags: scala

I was trying to replicate an example from the book Scala in Depth. The example is to demonstrate how mutability is bad and people should prefer immutability.

However, my little experiment has failed and the program exhibits weird behaviors. Here is my program:

```
class Vector2D(var x: Double, var y: Double) {
  def -(other:Vector2D) = {
    x = x - other.x
    x = y - other.y
    this
  }
  def magnify(amt: Double) : Vector2D = {
    x *= amt
    y *= amt
    this
  }
  override def toString = s"Vector2D($x, $y)"
}
```

The second function is copied from the book. I had to add two functions to make the results look like what the book demonstrated.

The program stopped working on the first function: `-`

I used Scala REPL:

```
scala> val x = new Vector2D(1,1)
x: Vector2D = Vector2D(1.0, 1.0)

scala> val y = new Vector2D(-1, 1)
y: Vector2D = Vector2D(-1.0, 1.0)

scala> x - y
res0: Vector2D = Vector2D(0.0, 1.0)
```

This does not look very correct...also I tried `this.x = this.x - other.x`, same as y. I got a different result but not the result I wanted. What's wrong with the program?? How can I fix it??

Comment: in Scala, `x - y` is equivalent to `x.-(y)`

Comment: Do you mean `x = y - other.y` not `y = y - other.y` in the first function?

Comment: looks like you get strange answers because `x - y` changes `x`

Comment: I mean, your `-` method in `Vector2D` mutates current instance, which will never be expected from a method with name `-`.

Comment: also, you assign `x` 2 times and `y` 0 times in `-`, so the subtraction doesn't work

Comment: @wwkudu Wait, I'm confused. The first function means to subtract x coordinates and y coordinates of two variables. `x = x - other.x` and `y = y- other.y`

Comment: @wwkudu THIS IS A TYPO!! I never spotted it! Thank you!

Comment: We've all been there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign `x` 2 times and `y` 0 times in `-`, so the subtraction doesn't work.
Change second line of `-` method from `x = y - other.y` to `y = y - other.y`.

Comment: THANK YOU! I never spotted it as a TYPO. I thought something was wrong with the infix operator or the use of `this`. Gosh I feel silly!